# Finding changes in a list then storing specific values into an array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, standard-deviation, mathnet-numerics

I have a class:

```
 namespace XMLParserAverage11
 {
     public class cPoint
     {
        public string point;
        public string time;
        public double xPoint;
        public double yPoint;
        public double StdDevX;
        public double StdDevY;
        public string csv;

       public cPoint(string n, double x, double y)
       {
           this.point = n;
           xPoint = x;
           yPoint = y;
       }

 }
}
```

This is used to store information obtained from reading an XML file and then it is put into

```
List<cPoint> Sorted
```

What I would like to do is store the "xPoint" into an array and the "yPoint" into another array for all "point" [that has the same value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tserx.jpg). This is so I can ultimately use `Statistics.PopulationStandardDeviation()`from Mathnet.Numerics NuGet package which requires a double array and calculate the total standard deviation of xPoint and yPoint per same "point" in List Sorted.

```
if (measurementType == "Body")
{
    double a = Convert.ToDouble(xOffset);
    double b = Convert.ToDouble(yOffset);
    cPoint Point = new cPoint(location, a, b);
    Point.time = endTime;
    //  Point.point = location;
    //   Point.xPoint = Convert.ToDouble(xOffset);
    //    Point.yPoint = Convert.ToDouble(yOffset);
    sorted.Sort((x, y) => x.point.CompareTo(y.point));
    //   double[] balanceX = {Point.xPoint};
    //  double[] balanceY = {Point.yPoint};
    if (sixSig == true)
    {
        List<cPoint> pointList = new List<cPoint>();
        // Select all the distinct names
        List<string> pointNames = location.Select(x => xOffset).Distinct().ToList();

        foreach (var name in pointNames)
        {

            // Get all Values Where the name is equal to the name in List; Select all xPoint Values
            double[] x_array = pointList.Where(n => n.point == name).Select(x => x.xPoint).ToArray();
            Point.StdDevX = Statistics.StandardDeviation(x_array);

            // Get all Values Where the name is equal to the name in List; Select all yPoint Values
            double[] y_array = pointList.Where(n => n.point == name).Select(x => x.yPoint).ToArray();
            Point.StdDevY = Statistics.StandardDeviation(y_array);
        }

        csvString = Point.time + "," + Point.point + "," + Point.xPoint + "," + Point.yPoint + "," + Point.StdDevX + "," + Point.StdDevY;
        Point.csv = csvString;
        sorted.Add(Point);

    }
    else
    {
        csvString = endTime + "," + location + "," + xOffset + "," + yOffset;
        Point.csv = csvString;
        sorted.Add(Point);
    }
}
```

My output will eventually resemble [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCWXV.jpg).
Obviously I'm a beginner so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code is a little confusing.where is `sorted` populated? , in the last line? Do you calculate the `PopulationStandardDeviation` with only 1 value? why do you expect in the foreach loop two different outcomes for `a` and `b` if you use the same single value from `balanceX` ?

Comment: this sounds like an XY problem

Comment: @Mong Zhu there's about 500 extra lines of code that I didn't want to post but `sorted` is initialised as a `cPoint` list in another class. Everything is stored initially in `cPoint Point` then added to `sorted` when all the calculations etc. are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

ok Here is a small Console application which illustrates the procedure that you are looking for I think. I cut down (and renamed) your class `cPoint` for this purpose:

```
public class C_Point
{
    public string point;
    public double xPoint;
    public double yPoint;

    public C_Point(string n, double x, double y)
    {
        this.point = n;
        xPoint = x;
        yPoint = y;
    }
}

class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<C_Point> pointList = new List<C_Point>();

        pointList.Add(new C_Point("P1", 1, 11));
        pointList.Add(new C_Point("P1", 2, 22));
        pointList.Add(new C_Point("P1", 3, 33));
        pointList.Add(new C_Point("P10", 101, 111));
        pointList.Add(new C_Point("P10", 201, 211));
        pointList.Add(new C_Point("P10", 301, 311));

        // Select all the distinct names
        List<string> pointNames = pointList.Select(x => x.point).Distinct().ToList();

        foreach (var name in pointNames)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", name);

            // Get all Values Where the name is equal to the name in List; Select all xPoint Values
            double[] x_array = pointList.Where(n => n.point == name).Select(x => x.xPoint).ToArray();

            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", x_array));

            // Get all Values Where the name is equal to the name in List; Select all yPoint Values
            double[] y_array = pointList.Where(n => n.point == name).Select(x => x.yPoint).ToArray();

            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", y_array));
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

You can just copy paste it in a console project and let it run.
It will display the array values with the name of the point, in your case the `Location`.
Did I got closer to your Problem?

EDIT 2:

when you try to get all the distinct names of your points you need to extract them from the `List` where all the points are.

Here you try to select something from a `string` as it seems. This will not work.

```
// Select all the distinct names
List<string> pointNames = location.Select(x => xOffset).Distinct().ToList();
```

Instead use the `sorted` List. I think you have them all in there, don't you?
`Select(x=>x.point)` means: the `x` is a placeholder for any element (in your case of type `cPoint`) inside your list. after the `=>` you specify which property of the elements should be selected! in this case `x.point`. The result will be a list of all the values of this property of all elements. The `Distinct` call gets rid of the multiple entries.

This: `(x => xOffset)` does not work because it is not a valid expression and because you have no property `Offset` that could be selected in your class `cPoint`

This will not work either:

```
double[] x_array = pointList.Where(n => n.point == name).Select(x => x.xPoint).ToArray();
```

because your `pointList` is empty! You need to use again the `List` with all your points!

Hope this helps you further. Write me if not.

For more information please read more about [Lambda expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb397675.aspx)

Comment: `sorted` is a bunch of data that I have read from an XML file. All of the `xPoint` and `yPoint` values will always be unique but `point` will not.  The code should create a `double[] x_array` and `double[] y_array` for each new 'point' in 'sorted' or just add to the existing array if `point` is already contained somewhere in `sorted`.   Hopefully this clears some of the confusion up? Thanks for the help

Comment: I've updated my original question with an image showing what my eventual output will be. Hopefully this will clarify things.

Comment: @ChristopherDyer ok I think I understood you a little better. I edited my answer. Have a look

Comment: Firstly, my apologies for such a late response, I was taken off this project for two weeks. This is exactly what I want.  Can you give some guidance to integrating your code within my project to the point where I am storing the x and y values in the double arrays? I'm struggling with modifying your code for my purpose as this is my first c# project. Thank you.

Comment: @ChristopherDyer I have updated my answer, have a look

Comment: @ChristopherDyer glad I could help